# Prestashop _PS_MODE_DEV_ and WebService

Tags: web-services, prestashop-1.6

I am in a particular situation.
I use the prestashop webservice with a cron to update my prestashop database and synchronize with my management software.
The problem is that i have to set  _PS_MODE_DEV_ to OFF for many reasons, and in particular for some errors that prestashop fix setting _PS_MODE_DEV_ to OFF.

For example a checkout error:
http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/344514-solved-unable-to-save-account-parsererror-one-page-checkout/page-2

BUT if a set _PS_MODE_DEV_ to OFF, my WebService stop working.
How can i solve it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I end up on a dirty solution found on https://www.e-connecteur.fr/content/comment-afficher-les-erreurs-du-webservice-prestashop (French).

The solution consists in turning _PS_DEV_MODE_ on only for the api by detecting the request url, and replacing a line in `defines.inc.php`

`if (_PS_MODE_DEV_ === true OR substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, 4) == '/api')`